# sign in a Devise managed user by code

Tags: devise

I'm using Devise to manage user authentication. Given we have the email and password of a registered user account, can I sign in this account with code?

I'm asking this is because I need to provide a login server api for mobile apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just I'm quite new to Rails, the Devise user class has its public functions to call to login/logout, it's all in the documentation